# bratreader installation problem: command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-n_qu_f2a-build/

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, python, pip

I failed to  install bratreader (https://github.com/clips/bratreader) in various ways:

```
giuliano@giuliano-VirtualBox:~/Documenti$ sudo -H pip install 
bratreader-master
Collecting bratreader-master
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bratreader-
master (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bratreader-master

giuliano@giuliano-VirtualBox:~/Documenti$ sudo -H pip install 
bratreader-master.zip
Processing ./bratreader-master.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-JfVutP-
build/setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-JfVutP-build/


giuliano@giuliano-VirtualBox:~/Documenti$ sudo -H pip3 install 
bratreader-masterCollecting bratreader-master
Collecting bratreader-masterCollecting
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bratreader-
masterCollecting (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bratreader-masterCollecting



giuliano@giuliano-VirtualBox:~/Documenti$ sudo -H pip3 install 
bratreader-master.zip
Processing ./bratreader-master.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 
10, in <module>
    from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, map
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", 
line 1, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import plistlib
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
ImportError: No module named 'xml.parsers'; 'xml' is not a package
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 15, in <module>
    import xml.dom, xml.dom.minidom
ImportError: No module named 'xml.dom'; 'xml' is not a package

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, map
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import plistlib
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
ImportError: No module named 'xml.parsers'; 'xml' is not a package

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-n_qu_f2a-build/
```

It seems to be a more general problem, not related to bratreader.
Any suggestions?

[details: Ubuntu 17.04 within Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.22, installed on Windows 10 64-bit, pip-9.0.1 setuptools-36.0.1]

Comment: There is nothing to install. Just use `git` to clone the repository and use the modules directly.

Comment: I see now that there's no setup.py inside.  I'm an absolute beginner. Thanks